# Reload page jumps part way down the page

Tags: bug, status-completed, android-app

When reloading a page that was opened by tapping a notification, the app will jump down to the specific question/answer, when reloading the page. This is most likely the default behavior since reloading the page would trigger the same parameters to scroll down, but if possible, when reloading, that should be removed from the url.

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in 1.0.84.

After loading the first time we'll set a flag indicating not to keep scrolling to the linked post.